# Understanding proof of stability in an stochastic differential equation

Tags: finance, stochastic-differential-equations, stability-theory

I am currently doing my thesis on stochastic models applied to interest rates. I am partly basing myself on the article "*Stability Behavior of Some Well-Known
Stochastic Financial Models*" of T. E. Govindan and R. S. Acosta Abreu.

But i'm having trouble understanding the next part (page 1373):

Be
\begin{equation}
  r(t)=e^{-k t}r_{0}+\mu(1-e^{-k t})+\sigma e^{-k t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{k s}\sqrt{r(s)}dW(s)
 \end{equation}

Applying Ito’s formula to the process $X(t)=e^{k t}r(t)$ gives.
\begin{equation}
 X(t)=r_{0}+\mu(e^{k t}-1)+\sigma\int^{t}_{0}e^{k s}\sqrt{r(s)}dW(s).
\end{equation}
Taking expectations on both sides, we get
\begin{equation}
 \mathrm{E}X(t)=r_{0}+\mu(e^{k t}-1).........(1)
\end{equation}
Next, consider the processes $X(t)$ and $X^{*}(t)=e^{k t}r^{*}(t)$, where $r(t)$ and $r^{*}(t)$ are solutions with the initial conditions $r(0)=r_{0}$ and $r^{*}(0)=r^{*}_{0}$ respectively.
Exploiting again Ito’s formula, we obtain the following stochastic
differential for $\lvert X(t)-X^{*}(t)\lvert^{2}$:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
 &d\lvert X(t)-X^{*}(t)\lvert^{2}=\sigma^{2}e^{k t}(\sqrt{X(t)}-\sqrt{X^{*}(t)})^{2}dt\\
 &+2\sigma e^{k t/2}(X(t)-X^{*}(t))(\sqrt{X(t)}-\sqrt{X^{*}(t)})dW(t)
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Integrating both sides and then taking expectation, we get
\begin{equation*}
 \mathrm{E}\lvert X(t)-X^{*}(t)\lvert^{2}=\lvert r_{0}-r_{0}^{*}\lvert^{2}+\sigma^{2}\int_{0}^{t}e^{k s}\mathrm{E}(\sqrt{X(s)}-\sqrt{X^{*}(s)})^{2}ds .....(2)
\end{equation*}
From equations (1) and (2), it follows that
\begin{equation}
 \mathrm{E}\lvert r(t)-r^{*}(t)\lvert^{2}\leq\lvert r_{0}-r_{0}^{*}\lvert^{2}e^{-k t}+\frac{3}{2}(r_{0}+r^{*}_{0})(1-e^{-k t})e^{-k t}+\frac{3\sigma^{2}k}{k}(\frac{1}{2}-e^{-k t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2k t}), \hspace{4mm} t\geq 0.....(3)
\end{equation}

I can't understand how (3) can be obtained from (1) and (2). I've tried to figure out a way to use Gronwall's lemma but it doesn't seem to work. I hope someone can give me an idea and thanks in advance for taking the time to read.